# Unity: How to rotate first person camera by dragging touch across?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, touch

Maybe its worth noting that I am using the Fingers asset for touch/mouse.

Okay so I have a turret that has a first person camera, on PC it uses the axis Mouse X/Y as I move the mouse around the camera follows. But I need for Mobile to work with the axis Mouse X/Y to drag the camera using touch.

What I need help with is:
As my fingers drags across the screen to move the camera's rotation not position. The position is modified by the vehicle.

This is the code I use for PC first person, moving the mouse:

```
 x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSpeed * 0.02f;
 y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed * 0.02f;

 Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0f);

 turretHeadToMove.rotation = rotation;
```

How would I use touch dragging to move the rotation? instead of mouse?

Any help with this? Thank you

---

Here is the current code for touch

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        x += touch.deltaPosition.x * xSpeed * 0.02f;
        y -= touch.deltaPosition.y * ySpeed * 0.02f;

        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0f);

        turretHeadToMove.rotation = rotation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465323/unity-fps-rotation-camera)?

Comment: @Daniel yeah but that's for pc mouse, I would like to use touch to drag the rotation

Comment: As far as I know, touch and pc mouse behave the same way. `Input.mousePosition` and `Input.GetTouch(0).position` should be the same.

Comment: so how would I convert `Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")` to use `GetTouch(0)` ?

Comment: You can store the last touch position and `Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")` should behave similarly to `lastPos.x - currPos.x`, but I'm not sure, never used this `GetAxis` method.

Comment: @Daniel I updated the question but it's not as smooth, when I let go of the touch, the turret goes back to position it started.

Answer (score 1):

For touch you could use

> Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition

Try fiddle with something using this:

```
float strength = 2;

if (Input.touchCount == 1) { 
  if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
  {
    Vector2 touchDirection = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
    // Update ur transform.Rotate the way u desire
    // Different depending on using 1st person, 3rd person etc.
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated the question with the new touch code but it does not work right, I want it to be like for example Google Earth where you drag with your finger to slowly rotate to exactly where you want